# Why is the response.id and response.name returning null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to run some facebook graph api query but it is always returning null from the response argument. I am logged in already. Maybe is something basic but I can't figure out. Please help.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'theappid', // App ID
                channelUrl: 'www.website.com', // Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
            // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
            // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
            // will be handled. 

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
                    // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
                    // have logged in to the app.
                    testAPI();
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
                    // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
                    // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
                    // like this, for two reasons:
                    // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
                    // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
                    // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
                    FB.login();
                } else {
                    // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
                    // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
                    // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
                    // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
                    // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
                    FB.login();
                }
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
        // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name', function (response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                alert(response.id);
            });
        }

        $("#lkGetInfo").click(function () {
            testAPI();
        });

        $("#lkLogout").click(function () {
            FB.logout();
        });

    });
</script>

<!--Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to-->
<!--present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked.-->
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<br />
<a href="#" id="lkGetInfo">Get Some Info</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="lkLogout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Try console logging `response`, and see what it looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fiddled around abit with my app ID and got this:

```
error
    Object { message="An active access token ...about the current user.", 
    type="OAuthException", code=2500}
code
    2500
message
    "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type
    "OAuthException"
```

by doing this:

```
        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
        // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name', function (response) {
                console.log(**response**);
                alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                alert(response.id);
            });
        }
```

probably you missed to set the access toke or haven't run through the OAuth properly. Actuall I did expect to get prompted, but nothing happened.

hope that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/azHnd/3/

Comment: dude, you're right, I want to kiss you right now. It worked great after I place my token.